# How to retrieve and deploy metadata created by inactive users?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata, migration-tool, migration

When I'm trying to retrieve metadata (using ANT migration tool) that is created by a user that is currently inactive I get errors like below:

```
[sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity of type 'ListView' named 'Quote.myView' cannot be found
[sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity of type 'ReportType' named 'MyReportFolder/MyReport' cannot be found
[sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity of type 'Flow' named 'My_Flow' cannot be found
```

Is there a way to **automatically** retrieve and deploy metadata created by currently inactive users from one **prod org to another prod org**? Any Workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

you aren't specifying path name properly it seems. Specify pathname properly and give a try.

If you are still facing same issue means better to use "Changeset" (Orgs are related)